# Distributing a Java application on macOS

Tags: java, distribution, mac

I have developed a Java application for both Windows and MacOS. The application requires 2 separate jar files, 1 for the main application and then another is used to download and apply updates.

This will be the first time I have developed something for mac and I'm not too familiar with the OS in general. I was mainly wondering what the standard protocol is for distributing a Java application on mac that requires 2 separate jar files to run? I know you can just send the users the 2 jar files in a zip folder and they can use the application by double clicking the main file but was wondering if there was a more professional way of doing this?

I have looked at things like creating a .pkg file but the things I have looked at have all been for 1 jar file and I don't know enough about the OS to know if this would work with 2? The main issue being that the updater jar file needs to be able to overwrite the main program file, therefore they need to be separate so it can overwrite the file (or at least I presume they need to be separate and it is the same situation as Windows that an open file cannot be overwritten?).

Comment: Can someone explain why this is getting downvotes? I feel like it is a legitimate question that doesn't seem to be answered anywhere else I can find and is a question to do with distribution which is surely a part of the "System Development Life Cycle" this forum is meant for?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, but it's quite a broad question that'd be pretty hard to answer. Addressing this question isn't really easy, so I think people are just dropping their down-vote and moving along, unfortunately.

Comment: "I'm not too familiar with the OS in general" Fixing this should be your number 1 priority, IMO. Mac users have very high expectations for app quality, and unless you understand and embrace those, your app will get shat on, in terms of public perception. Unfortunately, you're at a bit of a disadvantage, because Java makes it really easy to ship really poor UX, particularly platform-specific UX. The UIs usually look like shit, there's Jars and installers and nags for JVM updates and stuff, that users don't like.

Comment: Ideally, you should find a way to conceal the fact that your app is Java based. The UI should look native. The menu bar should match Mac conventions. The app Icon should be high quality (at least 512x512). There should be no user-visible jars, pkgs, etc. I think these are the kinds of things you should look out for. For one, program installation is a very windows thing. Mac users except a single `.app` bundle, that they can move around, copy into `/Applications` to install, and move to trash to uninstall.

Comment: Apple used to publish a Java library called Apple Extensions that allowed you to control things like the title and icon your app uses in the Finder. They didn't just abandon it, they scrubbed their developer site of all evidence that it ever existed. Years later, though, the classes still existed in Apple JREs, so programs using them could still run. If that's still true, you can build against the open source reimplementation called Orange Extensions.